# given a point x find the nearest point in a set G that does not contain x

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

thanks in advance for any help.

Suppose I have a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a set   $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where G is not a vector space for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \notin G$.  I would like to find the point $y \in G$ such that the distance between x and y is shorter or equal to the distance between z and x, $\forall z \in G$.  How might I go about this?  An example would be appreciated.

Edit:
G is convex.

Comment: The (algorithmic) answer to this question depends strongly on the representation of $G$.  What form of description does $G$ have?  ... or is this not about an algorithmic approach?

Comment: z is an arbitrary point in the set G.  It is possible that y = z since y is in G as well.  I want to find y such that the distance between x and y is less than or equal to the distance between x and z.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that G is convex.  I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G \neq \varnothing$, otherwise the problem is vacuous.

If by "$\forall z \in G$" you mean "for each *a priori* choice of a single $z \in G$":  Let $D$ be the disk of radius $||z-x||$ centered at $x$.  Compute $I = D \cap G$.  All $y \in I$ satisfy your description.

If by "$\forall z \in G$" you actually mean that:  Let $D_r$ be the disk of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  Incrementally increase the radius starting at $1$ by powers of two until $D_r \cap G \neq \varnothing$.  Binary search between the last power that included nothing of $G$ and the first that included something of $G$ until you find the minimum radius, $r_\text{min}$ such that $D_{r_\text{min}} \cap G \neq \varnothing$.  Note that this minimum may not exist.  The problem statement does not clarify that $G$ is finite or infinite and whether $G$ has limit points.  More specification is needed to resolve what to do when the minimum does not exist but an infimum does.

Comment: Your first description is the problem that I meant.  While I did not explicitly state so, G is uncountable infinite.  Therefore I can't solve for I (I want to be able to computationally find y such that there is one and only y).  Here is a trivial example of this problem.  Suppose I have a circle with a point that lies outside of the circle.  Find the point along the circle that is closest of all the points on the circle to x.  I'm looking for an algorithm that I could use to solve this problem in general.  If G was a vector space, I could use the projection of x onto G.  But G isn't.

Comment: Confusingly, the instantiation of the problem you describe here matches my second description.  Since we have no guidance what to do with infimum without minimum problem instances, we are stuck.  Since, furthermore, I have no guidance on how you intend to specify your sets $G$, there is nothing to add.

Comment: "Infimum without minimum" problem instance:  Set $n=1$, $G = (0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $x=\{-1\}$.  Which point $y \in G$ is closest to $x$?

Comment: Yes you are correct I did mean case 2.  My mistake.  I know that G is convex (see my earlier edit) so there should be a minimum distance as I have specified.  If G was a vector space, I could treat x as a vector and project x onto G and from there determine what y is.  Considering that this is such a trivial problem there has got to be a simple solution.  using a binary search would not give the exact solution (However it would give it close enough that the error wouldn't be computationally significant)

Comment: The set $G$ in my example is convex.  The minimum still does not exist.

Comment: If G is not closed then yes.  Good point.

Comment: Would you say that using a binary search is the most efficient then?

Comment: Depends entirely on how difficult it is to compute the intersections (which depends on the representation of $G$).  Historically, searching by golden mean sections rather than binary sections is more efficient.  (There are somewhat general theorems to this effect.)  The "trouble" is that the radii aren't rational, so some complications are involved in an actual implementation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that technique.  Could you give a brief pseudo explanation or good link that I could check out? (wikipedia didn't really help).

Comment: Golden section search:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search

Comment: Ok I'll take a look.  Thank you for the help.